# ADB won't recognize devices unless plugged into USB hub

Tags: android, adb

This is an odd one. When I'm at work I have my Macbook Pro plugged into a monitor, which has built-in USB ports. I plug the USB from the monitor into my laptop, and then plug Android phones or tablets into the monitor. This works great and there are no problems running or debugging using ADB.

However, if I plug devices directly into my laptop they will not be detected. They receive power but do not show up in ADB. I have tried the following:

- Rebooted the laptop
- Killed and restarted ADB
- Installed Android Studio updates
- Used all USB ports on the laptop
- Used different USB cables
- Used different USB devices, spanning all Android versions

What gives? I am running High Sierra 10.13.6. Any ideas? I can post more information if needed but I'm not sure what will be helpful.

Comment: To add more to the list, try on a device in developer options: "Select USB Configuration": MTP, "Revoke usb debugging authorization", disable and reenable usb debugging and plug in. Also compare "adb devices" output to Android Studio's available devices to run app.

Comment: This is probably not a *software* problem at all, but rather minor incompatibilities of a newer USB port not quite operating in a legacy mode, or the phone diverging from spec in the opposite direction than the computer.  Try getting a cheap hub to use at home.  Question perhaps better belongs on https://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: Note you can see all USB devices in the system report - chances are you'll see it's just not found at all, and that ADB isn't involved in the issue.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I've had this laptop for two years, and this problem started in the past month. It's not specific to any one device either. Very odd.

Comment: If you see the devices in system report with valid USB VID/PID I'd be prepared to consider it an ADB issue.  But without that, I'm going to stick by the idea that it is a "slightly out of spec in opposite directions" issue with the USB implementations - possibly one made worse by component aging or an OS update.  The problem at the moment is that you have an all-or-nothing test; you need to look in the middle, and that middle is system report.  `Apple->About this Mac->System Report->USB`

Comment: @ChrisStratton I went to the system report while I have a phone plugged in and it only lists two items: 

Bluetooth USB Host Controller and Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad. So it's not ADB. But what now?

Comment: It's some sort of USB incompatibility.  You can buy a new laptop.  Or you can buy a new phone.  Or you can just do what you know works, and use a hub in between.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been determined to be a hardware issue, or at the outside, a USB stack bug.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Closing seems fair, as ADB seems off the hook. I don't think it's a phone issue though, as I've tried with about six devices, all with the same behavior.

Comment: You might look on ask different for known macbook USB issues; I have vague recollections of there being such.